# Use fold to count the number in range

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have an assignment:

> Use fold to count the number in range. Complete below function numberInRange with the type int list * int * int -> int that takes three arguments (int list, int, int) and returns an int with the number count between lo and hi.
>
> ```
> fun fold (f, acc, xs) =
>     case xs of
>          [] => acc
>        | x::xs' => fold (f, f (acc, x), xs')
>
> fun numberInRange (xs, lo, hi) = (* ... *)
>
> val myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>
> val x = numberInRange (xs, 2, 7)
> ```

Can somebody tell me how to do this, I'm struggling with this problem of my assignment

Comment: It isn't immediately obvious to me what the purpose of this function is... what does "an int with the number count between lo and hi" mean? How is the count between `lo` and `hi` not simply `hi - lo`? If you can supply one or more examples, or a more clear explanation, it would be easier for you to solve the task.

Comment: Basically, I have a list of numbers right, let's say [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. I need a function that uses the list as one parameter, and a range. Let's say the low of the range is 2 and the hi is 5. I need it to tell me between 2 and 5, there are 4 numbers

Comment: I believe the hi and lo isn't the index, but the numbers themselves

Comment: Ohhh! So it counts how many numbers in `xs` that are within the closed interval of `lo` and `hi`! Wow, not sure why that was so tricky for me to understand.

Comment: I think it might help to know that this type of fold is an abstraction of the very common "do something with the list's head (`x`) and the result of recursing on its tail (`acc`)" pattern.

Answer (score 2):

`fold` takes three arguments, which are easiest to explain in reverse order:

- The third, `xs`, is the list to process.
- The second, `acc`, is the result if `xs` is empty.
- The first, `f`, is the function to use to combine `acc` with elements of `xs`, in turn.

Due to the recursive nature of `fold`, the result of `f` from one call is used as the `acc` for the next call. This makes sense, because the `acc` for the recursive call will be the result if the rest of the list is empty (meaning that we've reached the end of the list); so the result of the overall `fold` is the result of the last call to `f`. The name `acc` is short for "accumulator", but it's helpful to think of it as a "partial result" or "result in progress": it's the result for the part of the list that we've already processed.

So, for example:

- `fold f acc []` is `acc`
- `fold f acc [a]` is `f (acc, a)`
- `fold f acc [a, b]` is `f (f (acc, a), b)`
- `fold f acc [a, b, c]` is `f (f (f (acc, a), b), c)`

For your case, it's hopefully clear that you need `xs` to be `xs` (since that's the list that you need to process), and that you need `acc` to be `0` (since that's the result you want if `xs` is empty).

So, that just leaves `f`. Remember that, if `x` is an element of the list, and `acc` is the result after all the elements *before* `x`, then `f (acc, x)` needs to give the result after all the elements *up through* `x`.

So in your case, `f (6, 18)` needs to be "The number of elements of a list that are between `hi` and `lo`, if the list ends with `18` and there are 6 such elements before that." In other words, it needs to be `7` if `18` is in the desired range, and otherwise `6`. Do you see how to do that?

---

Now, I should point out that the above is what's sometimes called a "test-taker's" solution, taking advantage of the fact that you won't have been assigned this problem if there weren't a solution. Specifically, the above presupposes that `numberInRange` can be implemented using `fold`, and further, that `numberInRange` can be implemented as just a single call to `fold` with appropriate arguments. And as it happens, that assumption is correct. But the above approach would give us *an* answer even if `numberInRange` *couldn't* be implemented as a single call to `fold` (say, if some post-processing were required) — it's just that the answer would be wrong! So once you have your answer, it's important to examine it to make sure that it really does behave the way that `numberInRange` is supposed to. (And it's a good idea to test it a bit. Even the great Donald Knuth once wrote, "Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it.")

Answer (score 2):

While you can use `fold` to solve this exercise, since you seem stuck before even trying, I would suggest you instead go back one step and apply list recursion. Take one element out of the input list at a time: If it is within the interval, add one to the result, otherwise don't.

```
fun numberInRange ([], lo, hi) = ...
  | numberInRange (x::xs, lo, hi) =
    if ...
    then ...
    else ...
```

Some leading questions:

- What would be a good return value for the empty list?
- When should the function call itself?

Once you have any kind of solution, turning it into one that uses `fold` becomes easier.

Comment: Sound advice. (This is what I usually do when I'm certain there's a fold but I can't see it.)